# Evaluate $ \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} x\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{T}\right)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How do you evaluate the integral

$$ \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} x\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{T}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x?$$

I am trying to integrate this, however I don't seem to get the correct answer, which is

$$ \frac{-2T}{\pi^{2}n^{2}}( 1 - \cos(n\pi )). $$

I tried integration by parts with

\begin{align}
u &= x,  &\mathrm{d}u &= 1; \\
\mathrm{d}v &= \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{T}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x, & v &= \frac{T}{n\pi} \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{T}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Looks good so far. What did you do then?

Comment: You got all the things you need, just apply the formula (:

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is an odd function. Since the interval of integration is symmetric around $0$, the integral is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

When integrating $u'v$ by parts, the integral will become $uv'$. You need to choose what is $u'$ in such a way that you can integrate it, and that the product $uv'$ is simpler to process.

In the case at hand, omitting all the constants for conciseness,

$$\int x\cos(x)\,dx$$
you can choose $u'=x$, then $u=x^2$ leading to
$$\int x^2\sin(x)\,dx,$$
not really easier.

Or you can choose $u'=\cos(x)$, then $u=\sin(x)$ leading to

$$\int \sin(x)\,dx,$$the right choice.